# *ngIf equivalent in TypeScript code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

How is it possible check if the component property is undefined within the TypeScript code, in a method for instance?

In .html component template it is possible to do such check as a conditional on displaying html elements. To avoid the diplay in case they do not exist or not initialized yet.

```
<div *ngIf="exampleComponentProperty"></div>
```

Is it possible to do the same check in .ts? How would the expression look then?

```
if (this.exampleComponentProperty != null) {
// some code...
}
```

did not seem to work.

Comment: what's your `exampleComponentProperty ` on initial?

Comment: there was no initialization, it was exampleComponentProperty: string;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try condition with avoiding all the possibilities :

In TS :

```
if (this.exampleComponentProperty && this.exampleComponentProperty != undefined && this.exampleComponentProperty != null) {
    // write code...
}
```

In HTML :

```
 <div *ngIf="exampleComponentProperty && exampleComponentProperty != undefined && exampleComponentProperty != null"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write

```
if (this.exampleComponentProperty) {
// some code...
}
```

Or

```
if (this.exampleComponentProperty != undefined) {
// some code...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this property is required for display this component you should load it in resolver.
https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data